# Suggestion: Shared Stack Exchange Privileges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, privileges

Foreword: The logic behind this request is to encourage questions to be asked on the appropriate community sites, as well as to drive more traffic to these sites. I admit that I have been guilty at times of posting more generic questions on Stack Overflow even though a better site may have existed for my question simply, because I had more rep on that site that I wished to build upon.

I would like to see more of the [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) shared between the various sites on the Stack Exchange Network. I suggest they be broken up as shown below. I'll ignore the privileges gained with 100 and less rep since those are a given when joining a new community.

### Shared Privileges

```
25,000 - access to site analytics
3,000 - cast close and reopen votes
1,500 - create tags
1,000 - established user
1,000 - create gallery chat rooms
500 - access review queues
250 - view close votes
200 - reduce ads
125 - vote down
```

I believe most of these are relatively innocuous, but beneficial to established users. For example, I sometimes like to know what the votes on a particular question or answer are. Even if I want to suggest a new tag that I may be novice in, the higher "approve tag" privilege would weed out bad suggestions.

### Distinct Privileges

```
20,000 - trusted user
15,000 - protect questions
10,000 - access to moderator tools
5,000 - approve tag wiki edits
2,500 - create tag synonyms
2,000 - edit questions and answers
```

I see these as appropriately delegated to users with specialized expertise in a particular topic, though an argument can be made even for some of these to be shared as well.

Ok, so here's the actual **question**! :)

Does anyone else agree with any part of this suggestion, or am I way off base? I couldn't find any other discussion or questions regarding this particular idea.

Comment: I think quite a few of your Shared privileges fall into your description of Distinct privileges. Many should be reserved for those who understand or are experts in a certain topic. If you've earned cast close and reopen votes on Stack Overflow that doesn't necessarily mean you know what's appropriate for Bitcoin.SE or many of the other sites around the network. You should establish yourself within each community to have its privileges.

Comment: I think downvote (especially for answers), close/reopen vote, review & tag creation privileges require specific domain knowledge which different across SE sites, so I want to keep them as distinct privileges. Viewing total vote counts & close votes for your posts are reasonable for shared privileges, but still depends to each site policy.

Answer (score 15):

Keep in mind that the rep levels vary by site, some have higher thresholds than others.  Most notably beta sites have much lower thresholds than fully graduated sites.  So how would you account for that?

But ignoring that, let's look at your "Shared Privileges" one by one.

> 25,000 - access to site analytics

Not having this one myself (except on MSE, which barely counts), I'm not going to address this one in great detail.  I don't see the harm in exposing it since it doesn't seem to be geared to moderation, but one of the fun "hey, look at this" privileges, which should be an honor to get - so why devalue it.

> 3,000 - cast close and reopen votes

If you think this doesn't require domain knowledge of the site in question, then you are misguided.  The only people who should be closing or reopening questions on sites are people well versed in that specific site.  While there are certain questions we know are off-topic even without the 3K rep, you'd rather have the people with experience on that site setting the moderation policy on that site (which includes deciding what is on or off-topic).  Just because I have 3K on SO doesn't mean you should be trusting me to close questions on Law.SE.

> 1,500 - create tags

This one is unique to SO, I believe.  On most sites it is much less.  But still, tag creation requires some knowledge about the tagging policy on that site, so you still want site specific expertise, and meet the minimum rep target on that site.

> 1,000 - established user

**Viewing vote counts** is another non-moderation "fun" privilege.  I don't see the harm, but I don't see the benefit to exposing it to everyone.  Originally, the only reason this was a privilege is the strain on the server due to the extra queries involved.  But you also don't really *need* to know it.  If you are really invested in the site, you can earn 1000 rep without too much trouble (and hint, you can see the vote splits with the timeline view anyway, so you don't even need the privilege), and there are user scripts that do it (thanks to Cody Gray for reminding me they exist)

**An expanded usercard** is supposed to be an honor, so having it on one site doesn't mean you should automatically be entitled to it on another site.

> 1,000 - create gallery chat rooms

Don't use chat, don't know the privilege, won't comment on it.

> 500 - access review queues

Oh dear lord **NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO**.  We don't need someone who is a foodie (from Seasoned Advice) reviewing questions on SO (nor does that foodie want a programmer reviewing Food.SE questions.

> 250 - view close votes

<s>The first one that I think is actually reasonable.  If you are experienced enough on any SE site to have this one, you should be experienced enough to know what this means.  It is helpful to know when you ask a question to know whether it is getting close votes, especially when a comment isn't left on the site</s>

As [Servy reminded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354869/suggestion-shared-se-privileges/354870?noredirect=1#comment503253_354870) me, the "View Close Votes" privilege is misnamed.  While it does allow you to view close/reopen votes on your own question, it also allows you to cast said votes, which we've already said was a mistake when talking about the 3K "universal" privilege above.  In this case, the problem is mostly with users trying to reopen their own questions when they don't belong, less about them closing their own questions.

> 200 - reduce ads

This is revenue for SO, Inc.  The ads aren't too intrusive anyway, so why reduce it further.  If they bother you that much, then just use an ad blocker.

> 125 - vote down

Not quite as big of a **NOOOOOOOOOO** as the review privilege one, but we don't want random people who earned a minimal amount of rep on any SO site downvoting on any site.  You need to know the scope of the site to downvote.  (Frankly, you should know the scope of the site to upvote too, but that's a different argument completely).

---

So for your 9, "shared privileges", there are none that really make sense after getting reminded what the actual "view close vote" privilege included. In some cases, the privileges are honors or "fun" privileges that don't really impact much, but many have serious moderation/site quality implications that shouldn't be trusted to someone who is not active on the site.

Comment: For "access to site analytics", I can tell you that it is not really all that useful or interesting. With the exception of moderators and employees, it seems to me to be mostly one of those "for fun" bonus benefits, like you say. As far as ads go, SE has officially stated that they don't care if you block them, so the issue is only whether the site hides them or you have to do a bit of extra work. Same thing with viewing vote splits; there's a userscript you can install that will do this for you, so the built-in feature is merely there as a bonus for putting in the hard work to gain rep.

Comment: I actually would be totally fine with lowering the downvote threshold, though. Making it 100 so people with the association bonus can downvote seems eminently reasonable to me. Then again, it isn't that big of a deal because one upvoted and accepted answer gets you those 25 points. If you can't do that, maybe you shouldn't be downvoting.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not convinced on the downvoting thing.  Like I suggested, it is less horrible than access to the review queues, and I don't think it would destroy the site.  But my opinion is earning the privilege to downvote should require someone to invest a minimal amount of effort in the site rather than just hoping over from another site.  Look how many people suggest bad migrations.  Those clearly don't understand the scope of the target site, but you want to allow them to downvote content on that site too?

Comment: The vote counts can be viewed by everyone on the data SE. Actually, to have this privilege network-wide, the real requirement is to be able to use the data SE.

Comment: `250 - view close votes` is a misleading privilege name. The *actual* privilege is "you have full close/reopen privileges on questions you've asked".  If you think that closing/reopening requires domain knowledge, then I don't see how closing/reopening on questions you've asked wouldn't require domain knowledge.

Comment: @Servy really?  Well, then It's been so long that I thought it was just view the votes on your own questions.  So that does change my argument entirely

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, really.  Fortunately, 250 is still a higher bar than most question authors can meet, and even more fortunately, most of those between 250 and 3k don't know they have the privilege, and so tend to not use it to vote to reopen their off topic questions.  Unfortunately, when question authors *do* figure it out, it makes it much easier for bad questions to end up being reopened without being fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with allowing people with just the association bonus to downvote, because the fact that they can't but can upvote lends itself to some very asymmetrical voting pattern on Hot Network Questions (HNQ) on sites like the workplace.

However,

> 500 - access review queues

Would be a complete disaster. You need distinct domain knowledge and knowledge of the site's policies, which varies quite a bit per site, to effectively review anything. I for instance would have absolutely no business reviewing anything on Seasoned Advice.SE since I'm not a part of that community and have no clue what they allow and don't allow. This is a completly horrible idea.

> 3,000 - cast close and reopen votes

Again, close voting requires intimate domain knowledge. Do you know what very specifically is and isn't on topic on Drupal.SE? Why would you want to cast close votes there then?

Comment: Nope.  If you want to make objective voting on content, you should demonstrate that you have that objective understanding by participating on that site.

Answer (score 2):

I think, at least the privilege to see deleted posts (and maybe, even comments) would be very useful.

Maybe such an idea, if you have a privilege on at least 3 (or 5... or 10) sites, then you get this on the whole network.

It could be extended also for the diamond. Thus, if somebody is a mod on at least 3 sites, he could be a mod on all of them. It would make the very popular, cross-site mods as *de facto* CMs.

Side note: with not a very advanced usage of the SEDE, we can get roughly equivalent skills as

- seeing vote counts
- see reviews
- site analytics

with a little work.

Comment: Why would you want to see deleted posts on Japanese Language?  What value are they to you if you just had some confusion on how a sentence was structured?

Comment: @Makoto No. It wouldn't be a reason to even register the site, even if I would have 3 10k+ account (now I have 0). Although I like and honor the language and Japan, I think my life is already too short to start to learn it. But, for example, seeing your 500+ on 3 different sites makes me thinking, you could pretty well advice newbies also on the SuperUser, despite that you have only 170 there now.

Comment: *Maybe*, but I'd rather leave that sort of mentorship and leave the sort of power that entails to the users that actually invest lots of time there.  Having a breadth of knowledge helps when knowing where to ask and answer specific questions.  Having a depth of experience is important when dealing with community moderation, which is what most of the privileges being requested are for.

Comment: @Makoto Ok. Specifically about the deleted post access: not seeing them, *not even your own ones*, is a very annoying thing, despite that their majority is obviously crap. In the rare cases as they were deleted on some exceptional reason (for example, by accidentally disclosing special personal data), they should have been really deleted (i.e. by `DELETE` on the SQL level). In my opinion, making this to such a privilege, is a mistake from the SE policy-makers: 1) it makes a "hidden treasure" from a pile of crap 2) it makes the post-deleters unaccountable.

Comment: [You *can* see your own deleted posts...if you can see deleted posts in general.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users)  Nothing wrong with gating that behind the 10K privilege, since seeing deleted votes in general is a 10K+ rep level thing anyway.

Comment: @Makoto Getting to 10k+ only for that? To see *sometimes* some trash? No, it is a false treasure. It doesn't worth its price. To me, after 3k+, there is no more privilege which would worth the effort, thus the advancement is over. At least, on a single site. Although it could be interesting and useful to get to 3k+ on other sites. If the deleted posts would be visible roughly from 5k+ (as the 10k+ can do now), and they would be searchable from 10k+, including deleted comment access (as the mods can do it now), I would work for it.

Comment: @peterh 10k isn't just the ability to view deleted posts, it's also the ability to vote to delete (certain) posts (and undelete them).

Comment: Well...that's what the privilege is set to.  If you have a gripe with that, then you should post a feature request explaining and justifying why it should be lowered.

Comment: @Makoto But it is only my personal flavor, as I can see, most of us are focused to a single SE site (like you), cross-site SE users like me are rare (which is harder, although it has nice features: one gets more often some "surprise" (like a review ban for a year, or any similar), but it affects the overall cross-network privileges much lesser. Had I done my whole activity only on 1 or 2 SE sites, maybe I had got to 10k+ already on them (my overall rep is roughly 30k, but I have no 10k anywhere).

Comment: @Servy I've thought already a lot on it. Voting to delete is not very worthy to me, if I voted to down, with others together, it will be likely deleted. Voting to undelete would be useful, but it requires 20k (while already 10k is too big). Some "delete/undelete review queue" doesn't exist. Which results, if I voted to delete something, the delete vote will stay there forever (as far I know, they don't timeout), and the post will be only deleted after also a lot of other 10k+/20k+ found the post, *accidentally* (because also they can't list/search them), and voted to delete it.

Comment: @Servy The results to me, that the delete votes are practically unusable without some "semi-official" cooperation between the delete voters. In the case of the undelete votes, it may be interesting that it could help to fix falsely deleted posts (actually, I only got to 3k+ because I wanted to fix the numerous, well... *unwise* close/reopen decisions). But, first it requires the *double* of the already wasted effort to get to 10k+, and second, also it has the disadvantage of the lack of organized work of the post deletions.

Comment: @Servy Btw, in the last years a lot of mod elections happened, without the proportional growth of their sites. I think, the SE internally switched its focus from the community moderation to grow up an army of moderators in a short leash, without sharing this with the community. For example, on the ServerFault, mainly the mods are doing even the VtC/VtR work and the community self-regulation is only nominal. In my opinion, it is another step back to the old-style ircchannel/newsgroup/wikipedia era, to the single-person decisions instead community self-government.

Comment: @peterh On smaller sites, perhaps, on SO, that's just not even possible, even if SO *wanted* to.

Comment: @Servy The SO is roughly constant (in the sense new post/month) since roughly 2014, while the number of the mods doubled since 2014. Even knowing, that the old mods tend to be lesser active, why would it mean that their relative weight in the decisions isn't heavier? On the end of this way, we will get a Wikipedia No2.

Comment: @peterh So SO went from being thousands of mods short of having enough mods to moderate all of the content to thousands minus 5.  They still have nowhere near enough moderators to actually moderate everything, and when you actually look at moderation actions performed on the site by moderators and non-moderators, the moderators are dwarfed by orders of magnitudes.  The SO mods don't even manage to get through the moderator only issues (i.e. mod flags) effectively, let alone handling all of the community moderation for them.

Comment: @Servy I think in the case of the SO you may have right. It is still 2.5 times bigger as the other sites summed together (in the sense of new posts/month), while it has a maybe a tenth mods as the other sites summed together. I think the SO mods may be really busy, compared to the other sites. I think, the number of the mods should be proportional to the site activity (≈ new posts/month), but the mods should be so few as possible, *but* they should be enough to have time for the mod-only tasks.